# Enunciation in mathematical text (style)

Tags: article-writing

I'm writing longer mathematical texts (lecture notes) regularly, and I don't know where else to ask this question.

I regularly find myself *enunciating* (in the typographical sense) every statement I make. This means that I will put any even *vaguely* mathematical statement, not only theorems, corollaries, definitions, etc., into an enumerated environment in Latex. As of now, I always use *Remark* for them, and I feel like I'm overusing it.

**Question:** When do you write mathematical comments in some numbered environment, like *Discussion*, *Observation*, *Remark*, *Idea*, etc., and when do you write mathematical comments standalone in the running text? What other environments do you use to mark up mathematical comments?

**Edit:** The reason why I enunciate this often is simple: Later on in the text or in the lecture, I might want to refer to this comment. E.g. in a mathematical comment, we combine all results in an informal discussion on how to compute fibres of maps between prime spectra. This result is somewhat important as it will come up every now and then, but its statement in the lecture was more or less like an argument, making it difficult to encase this as a corollary.

Comment: This seems to be a two edged sword; if you use to often the `remark` environment, it will loose its meaning, but if you have too many environments like `observation` that describe similar things it will become pointless and unreadable. I am "pleased" to see that I'm not the only one that has made this observation... Maybe you should write more text that's not in an environment; just a paragraph and leave remarks for short and very important points to observe?

Comment: @JulesBesson Yeah, but there is a reason I forgot to mention why I enunciate so many mathematical comments, see my edit. But yeah, this seems to be a very good approach.

Comment: I dislike over-numbered papers and books. LaTeX has, in my opinion, led to ponderous style. Not every equation and not every statement needs to be labeled.